# Structure a Markdown file with many section and subsections

Tags: markdown

I have a Markdown document structure as follows:

```
- YAML Frontmatter
- Theory
- Evaluation 1
    Question
    Choices
    Solution
- Evaluation 2
    Question
    Choices
    Solution
```

Usually `---` is used to define the begin and end of FrontMatter.

I take advantage of `---` to also split Theory and each Evaluation.

Then I parse Frontmatter with a YAML parser and others with a Markdown parser.

**Structure**

```
---
title: Title
enabled: true
---

Theory

--- 

Question 1

[] Choice 1
[] Choice 2 has multiline text
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
   Nunc scelerisque turpis ac nisi gravida maximus. 

Solution 1

--- 

Question 2

[] Choice 1
[] Choice 2

Solution 2

---
```

**Problem**

How, inside each Evaluation, split Question, Choices and Solution?

I could use any other 'symbol' defined by me like `$$$`:

```
Question 2
$$$
[] Choice 1
[] Choice 2
$$$
Solution 2
```

Each choice starts with `[]` / `[X]` to set it as correct / wrong answer. Just an idea ...

I also need to split the choices using another symbol? Or another  strategy?

Basically I am trying to split subsections ...

**Is there a standard, or common, way to do this?**

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand the question, do you control the structure of the file or you have to parse existing files you can't control? Remark https://github.com/remarkjs/remark which is part of unified might be a good choice, I'd first check their ecosystem for existing solutions (because it's huge) and if necessary build a custom plugin, which shouldn't be too hard I think. Hope that helps.

Comment: I updated my entire question. Is it more clear now? Basically I am trying to split and entire markdown file into sections and subsections of markdown contents.

Comment: @MiguelMoura, what is the point of the "splits"? Is this something you want your editor to understand so it can help you navigate? Something you wish to render somehow? Something else?

Comment: I am loading the files, then splitting the sections, than parsing each section then saving the data to a database. Just a way to easily create a specific type of posts using a single file.

Comment: Each post has one Theory but Many Questions. Each Question has one Solution but many Choices. And all that will be saved in Post / Questions / Choices tables in a database.

Comment: In that case I think it's entirely up to you. Just pick something.

Comment: I know but I would like to be something that would not show in editor markdown preview used by the writer or at least that would to confuse the writer.

Comment: Maybe an empty HTML comment `<!-- -->`?